# How to place a custom view from .xib on top of all other viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, swift

My setup is a TabBarController with two ViewControllers connected. I need the custom view (audio player) to stay on top when the ViewControllers are changed.

Will I need changes to AppDelegate or SceneDelegate?
What is the solution after ios 13?

Answer (score 0):

Push the .xib on the topmost viewcontroller.

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter 
    {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

    if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
         while let presentedViewController = 
         topController.presentedViewController {
             topController = presentedViewController
         }

        // topController should now be your topmost view controller
    }
```

Comment: topmost would be the TabBarController in my case, correct?